# x in list for which f(x) is maximum

Tags: haskell, search, max

I am trying to find an `x` in a list for which `score x` has the maximum value. I tried `snd (maximum [(score x, x) | x <- codes])` which works, but I was wondering whether there were a faster way to do this, without actually storing both the function and the value.

Comment: Don't worry about the scores being "stored" -- the way Haskell and GHC work, they won't be.  For example, the compiled program `main = print (maximum [(2*x, x) | x <- [1..100000000000] :: [Int]])` may take about 10-15 minutes to run but will do so in small, constant memory, since the compiler will determine that neither the codes nor the scores need to be kept around to get the answer.

Comment: Be aware that if any codes have the same score, this will select between them by choosing the maximal code, however `Ord` is defined for that type.  This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: `snd . maximumBy (comparing fst) . map (score &&& id)` works for non-`Ord` types too.

Answer (score 7):

Your solution is fine. If you want some library help, you can use

```
maximumBy (comparing score) codes
```

Note that this, compared to your code, will perform more calls to `score`. If `score` is expensive to compute, your approach is better since it will compute `score` only once per list element.

Comment: @AJFarmar Before it was introduced, the idiom was ``compare `on` score``. This was so common that `comparing = on compare` was eventually added to the libraries.